# PHP application on Azure as "Console App"

Tags: php, azure, websocket

is there a way how to easily run a PHP application as from command line on Windows Azure?

I have a standard Web Application (on Azure) and I want to communicate using WebSockets.
So I need to have a WebSocket Server running all the time on Azure.

I use [Wrench project](https://github.com/varspool/Wrench/) which I need to run "all the time" to listen on some port and deal with messages from JavaScript-sended WebSocket.

So again - how easily run a *"persistent"* PHP application on Azure?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at [win32service](http://php.net/manual/en/book.win32service.php). Although to be honest when writing a WebSocket server, look at just about any language you can think of that isn't PHP, it is about the worst imaginable language for writing high-concurrency socket-driven server applications. I like Node.js, others can (and will) disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandrino's answer is fine, but I prefer [ProgramEntryPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557552.aspx#ProgramEntryPoint) for doing this sort of thing. The trouble with a background task is that (unless you build something on your own) nothing is monitoring it. Using `ProgramEntryPoint`, Windows Azure will monitor the process, and if it exits for any reason, the role instance will be restarted.

**EDIT**:

Sandrino points out that the PHP program isn't the only thing running. (There's also a website.) In that case, I'd recommend launching php.exe in `Run()` in `WebRole.cs`. `Process.Start` it and then do a `.WaitForExit()` on it. That way, if the process exits, the role itself will exit from `Run()`, causing the role instance to restart. See http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-other-web-servers-on-windows-azure for an example.

Comment: Wouldn't you use ProgramEntryPoint to run the actual website?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run your PHP script as a command line application you should use the [PHP CLI (command line interface)](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php).

```
php.exe -f "yourWebSocketServce.php" -- -arg1 -arg2 -arg3
```

Now, in order to run this in Windows Azure you'll need to define a [startup task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh124132.aspx) that runs this command. You'll see that the default task type is **simple**, which means that the startup of your role will block until the task finishes. But in your case running the WebSocket in PHP will be a blocking process, that's why you should change the type to **background** (this will make sure the instance continues starting up while your WebSocket server is running).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a WebSockets service on Azure. - Live XSockets.NET

Have a look at http://live.xsockets.net, an easy way of getting started, but it depends on what you are about to do on the "server side". This service i mention can be uses as a "message" dispatcher, to ntify "clients" on changes etc.. Hmm in other words it is a way of boosting "regular" web-apps..